# How to access vector objects in mapbox styles(road, water etc.)?

Tags: mapbox

In mapbox studio I have a lot of layers for customizations. Is there a way to access those layers programmatically with js. For example hide all WATER or ROAD layer on the map with js?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using https://github.com/mapbox/vt2geojson to get geojson data for whichever layers you are interested in and then use this data and add styling using mapbox gl js maps.

Hope that answers your question.